# How can I use SpringBoot to create a REST endpoint for file uploads?

Tags: java, spring

How to write a rest endpoint to upload a document using springboot microservices

I need to to write a document upload logic in service class and how can i write springboot to create a  rest end point in controller class give me some idea about it

Comment: A simple google search will give you tons of examples.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller you can use

```
@PostMapping(path = "/image", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<UserImageModel> uploadImage(@ModelAttribute UserImageRequestModel model) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userProfileService.postImage(model), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and for your request :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserImageRequestModel {

    private MultipartFile file;

    private Long userId;
}
```